# Java Swing GUI memory usage is high in Linux compared to Windows

Tags: java, swing, profiling, visualvm, jprofiler

We had a Java Swing application running in Windows which we recently supported for Linux platform.
In Windows, the application takes around 200 MB while launching but in Linux it is taking 300-400 MB of memory. Please let me know what are the parameters I need to watch and how can I fix this memory issue platform independent manner. I know Swing is not OS dependent then why this much variation. The Linux machine is Cent OS 7 and Gnome desktop.

Comment: Swing is depending on the operating system. There is no switch to make Swing use less memory on CentOS, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Do the applications ran/run in the same machine, but with different OS?

Comment: Application running in different machine but with the same hardware(8 GB RAM and 2 core CPUs).

Comment: Is this the heap size or a native process size? For the former, you could use a profiled and look into the biggest objects, the latter cannot be compared between Windows and Linux.

Comment: This is native memory size which I am getting by running top and ps in Linux. And thru task manager in Windows.